# Ways to check positive definiteness of bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, positive-definite

For each real number $\alpha$, we define the bilinear form $F_{\alpha}:\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by
$\displaystyle F_{\alpha}(((x_1, x_2, x_3), (y_1, y_2, y_3))
= 2x_1y_1 + (\alpha + 5)x_1y_2 + x_1y_3 + (\alpha + 5)x_2y_1
-(2\alpha + 4)x_2y_2 + 2x_2y_3 + x_3y_1 + 2x_3y_2 + 2x_3y_3.$
Find the set of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F_{\alpha}$ is positive definite.

Is there any other way to check positive definiteness instead of extracting the underlying symmetric matrix and the eigenvalues  ? Can the same be applied for quadratic forms ?

Comment: What about [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)?

Comment: @Reinhard Meier : So all the pivots after Gaussian elimination should be positive as  well!

Comment: Sylvester's criterion could be simpler if you have matrix elements that depend on variables. Gaussian elimination with variables can become ugly. By the way, is the first term really meant to be $2x_1x_2$? I wouldn't expect this is a bilinear form.

Comment: No the first term is $2x_1y_1$. My mistake.